# Who knows what method uses Mail.ru to download emails instantly

Tags: email, imap

Im working in an android email app using java and I download emails connecting with imap. I noticed my app takes a while to download emails in all providers, I tried some apps in the play store to find out if it was just me, but no, a lot of apps download emails same way I do, it takes a while. Until I found an interesting app, Mail.ru ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.mail.mailapp&hl=en ). This app download emails instantly, like hell!, there is no way they can download emails that fast, I tried a few email providers, Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo, AOL, Mail.com, Yandex, I even tried my own email domain and with all of them is the same, they download all emails instantly, you don't even notice.

I don't know, I wanted to ask because maybe someone have any idea what method they use to download that fast, I would really appreciate any tip, recomendation to improve the download speed of my app with all providers. Best Regards

Comment: They're probably getting headers only, and streaming them by requesting many UIDs all at once: `FETCH 1:500 (UID BODY.HEADER[FIELDS (From To Subject ...)])`

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways: They can start earlier, finish later or download less. Starting earlier means to issue the IMAP command before the user does, for example by noticing that the user always reads mail in the morning and so downloading everything in the background at six. Finishing later means to display something as soon as you have a first message ready, and continuing the download in the background. By the time the user is done with the first five messages you'll have had time to download at least fifty. Downloading less is to download only part of the message, as Max suggests, and complementing it later if necessary.